# Material UI Select will not display option choice when value is a list item

Tags: reactjs, select, react-hooks, material-ui

I have an MUI React Select component that is not displaying the MenuItem option. I initially set up my application to just take the updated `event.value` as a simple string. The below works fine:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Box, Input, MenuItem, FormControl, Select, InputLabel } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import axios from "axios";

function ProductSelect() {
    const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
    const [productType, setProductType] = useState('');
    const [productTypes, setProductTypes] = useState([]);
    const [runmode, setRunmode] = useState('dev');

    async function getProducts() {
        await axios
        .get(`https://myendpoint.myregion.mycloud.com/${ runmode }/product_types`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then((response) =>{
            var test_data = response.data.data;
            setProductTypes(
                test_data.map((x) => {
                    return {
                        product_name: `${x.product_name}`,
                        product_type_id: parseInt(`${x.product_type_id}`),
                    }
                })
            );
            setLoadingData(false);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
        if (loadingData) {
            getProducts();
        }
    }, []);

    const handleProductTypeChange = (event) => {
        setProductType(event.target.value);
    };

    const theme = createTheme({
        palette: {
          neutral: {
            main: '#24507C',
            contrastText: '#fff',
          },
        },
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
             {loadingData ? (
                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: '185px' }}>
                    <CircularProgress/>
                    <span style={{ justifyContent: "center", position: "fixed", top: "30%" }}>Loading. Please wait...</span>
                </Box>  
              ) : (
                <>
                    <FormControl style={{width: '250px', marginTop: '0px', marginBottom: '30px'}}>
                        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Product Type</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                            id="demo-simple-select"
                            value={productType}
                            label="Product Type"
                            onChange={handleProductTypeChange}
                        > 
                        {productTypes.map((option) => (
                            <MenuItem key={option.product_type_id} value={option.product_name} >
                                {option.product_name}
                            </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                </>    
              )}
              <Button color="neutral" variant="contained" cursor="pointer">Schedule</Button>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </div>
    );
};
export default ProductSelect;
```

However, each item in `productTypes` has 2 key-value pairs, product_type_id and product_name. In the above, I just pass the product name but I want to change the `MenuItem` value to a list and pass both items like this:

```
<MenuItem key={option.product_type_id} value={[option.product_name, option.product_type_id]} >
```

And then just insert the first item into `setProductType` like this:

```
const handleProductTypeChange = (event) => {
    setProductType(event.target.value[0]);
};
```

When I do this, it appears that the correct value gets plugged into the handler, but the selected item does not display. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the `value` of `MenuItem` and `Select` would need to match for correct display, if its not primitive type it need to be reference equal. What might be the purpose of making  `MenuItem`  to carry an array as `value`, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because your rendering the object. For the custom render value, **Select** component accept `renderValue` props which take a function and returns the value which can be render on webpage like string or number.

In your case, you just have to provide the **renderValue** props to **Select** component.

```
<Select
 labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
 id="demo-simple-select"
 value={productType}
 label="Product Type"
 onChange={handleProductTypeChange}
 renderValue={v => v.product_name}
>
{productTypes.map((option) => (
   <MenuItem key={option.product_key} 
     value={option} >                        
     {option.product_name}
  </MenuItem>
))}
</Select>
```